# FSO Writeblankline not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba, fso

Does any one know why the

```
  .writeblanklines 3
```

does not work? I've tried plenty of different ways and it always seems to just overwrite the line in the textfile.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim fsofolder As Folder
Set fsofolder = fso.GetFolder("U:\files")
Dim file1 As file
Dim a As Integer

Dim b As String
b = "U:\files\" & ListBox1.Value

fso.OpenTextFile(b, ForWriting).WriteBlankLines 3
fso.OpenTextFile(b, ForWriting).WriteLine (TextBox3.Value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

If you want to append content, then use `ForAppending` when opening the file.